# Close, open new magnific popup window via API

Tags: magnific-popup

Via a function, I am trying to close the currently open Magnific popup window and then open a new one.

What I have is an image gallery with custom title that includes links. The link closes the currently Magnific gallery of images and then open an AJAX window. This is for a script that uses the lightbox to show images and have an "add to cart" link which then opens a form (to select various options) via AJAX to then add the current image to cart.

```
function sunshine_add_to_cart(image) {
    var image_url = jQuery(image).attr('href');
    jQuery.magnificPopup.close();
    jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {
        src: image_url+'?sunshine_lightbox_cart=1'
      },
      type: 'ajax'
    }, 0);
    console.log(image_url);
}
```

The Magnific gallery successfully closes, but the AJAX never does. The console is logging the proper URL so that value does exist. The same URL opened via a standard link works just fine.

http://screencast.com/t/YoDiy2J76T - Standard link opens this - http://screencast.com/t/ee18Cl19tusI - add to cart ajax window just fine

http://screencast.com/t/WHGseoYiJn6g - The link in the image view closes the current gallery but does not open the new AJAX window. When the cart icon is clicked, it runs the "sunshine_add_to_cart" function via:

```
<a href="http://sunshinepro.dev/client-galleries/gallery/digital-downloads/223ad622-low-23192542-2/" onclick="sunshine_add_to_cart(this); return false;" data-image-id="2401"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout to open the 2nd popup window.  The basis for this answer is shown here [enter link description here](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/526)

I was not opening an ajax-type popup, so that has not been tested.

```
function sunshine_add_to_cart(image) {
    var image_url = jQuery(image).attr('href');
    jQuery.magnificPopup.close();

    window.setTimeout(open_new_popup, 100);
}

function open_new_popup() {
    jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
        src: image_url+'?sunshine_lightbox_cart=1'
    },
    type: 'ajax'
    }, 0);
    console.log(image_url);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. Problem for me was event bubbling. I had a link and a funktion which triggered onclick. I added return false and it worked. HTH